# How can sbt plugin set log level for 3rd party classes?

Tags: cassandra, sbt

I'm writing an sbt plugin (sbt 0.13.5) that provides tasks interacting with Cassandra (using the datastax driver). When the plugin's task is invoked, the sbt console prints log output created by 3rd party classes (the datastax driver), that should not displayed to the user (lines starting with `[pool-445-thread-1]`):

```
[sbt-pillar-plugin-play-sample] $ createKeyspace
[info] Creating keyspace my_keyspace at 192.168.33.99:9042
[pool-445-thread-1] WARN com.datastax.driver.core.FrameCompressor - Cannot find Snappy class, you should make sure the Snappy library is in the classpath if you intend to use it. Snappy compression will not be available for the protocol.
[pool-445-thread-1] WARN com.datastax.driver.core.FrameCompressor - Cannot find LZ4 class, you should make sure the LZ4 library is in the classpath if you intend to use it. LZ4 compression will not be available for the protocol.
[success] Total time: 2 s, completed Jun 10, 2014 11:07:20 PM
```

The FrameCompressor logs using slf4j, the sample project I created to test the sbt plugin is using play 2.3.0.

I already tried placing a `logback.xml` in `src/main/resources` of the sbt plugin, without success - the log messages still show up.

How is it possible to set the log level for the FrameCompressor to ERROR?